# Multiple GNU Octave Instances

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, octave

I've searched to try and find the answer to this question, but unfortunately, information is few and far between.

I need to be able to open multiple instances of GNU Octave to run a script which will convert a file. Each file takes approximately 5 minutes to convert, so for 10 files I'm waiting nearly 50 minutes.

However, I can (and have) manually open 10 instances of Octave and run the script manually in each instance. Is there a way to do this programmatically? So if I had 10 files, 10 different instances of Octave would open and each would run the script to convert 1 file. These conversions aren't dependent on each other, but if it's simple enough to communicate between the different instances of Octave, that would be a "nice to know".

Comment: Have a look at the parallel and mpi package http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php. What do you want to communicate between processes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use some of the high-level commands, like `system` and `popen` which Octave include for starting subprocesses. These subprocesses allow you to start new tasks or start another program. After performing the tasks it can observe the output, which is a way to communicate with the main program that starts the subprocesses.

You should take a look at the following [reference page](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Controlling-Subprocesses.html), which covers the different approaches.